# React native: SVG not loading in Material Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, svg, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using the `options` prop in `<Tab.Screen>` component to pass my SVG component but this draws a blank in the emulator (android)

```js
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-native-paper/react-navigation";
import HamburgerIcon from '../assets/navFooter/HamburgerIcon.js'
import Hamburger from "./Hamburger";
import { SvgUri, SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';


const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen 
        name='Hamburger'
        component={Hamburger}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon : <HamburgerIcon />,
          tabBarLabel: ''
        }}
      />
        ...

    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

below is how I made my SVG component - HamburgerIcon.js

```js
import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg";


export default function HamburgerIcon() {
    return (
        <Svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <Path d="M2 2H32M2 12.5H32M2 23H32" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </Svg>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows. This is my `options` in my `<Tab.Screen>` component

```
options={appOptions}
```

And this is the `appOptions` in another file to keep it clean and organised

```
export const appOptions: BottomTabNavigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
    <HomeIcon
      width={tabBarIconWidthCalculator(size, 7 / 6)}
      height={size}
      fill={color}
    />
  )
};
```

The `HomeIcon` simply refers to an SVG in my assets folder, and i use `react-native-svg` as well! I hope my answer can provide some help!

Comment: If that is by setting up a config in metro.config.js and then importing the svg that didn't work either

Comment: Okay, another reason why an icon was not showing for me was because of the ViewBox properties, i had to change it from `0 0 24 24` to `0 0 50 50` for example. I tried your svg in my app and it worked perfect for me.